# How to use map function on nested lists and converting strings to integers?

Tags: python

I would need to use the map function in Python(2.4.4) to add 1 to each item in the list, so I tried converting the strings into integers.

```
line=[['10', '13\n'], ['3', '4\n'], ['5', '3\n'], ['1', '13']]

map(lambda X:(X+1),int(line))
```

Is this not working because of `\n` and the nests?

Comment: Well, this is the error I get: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'`

Comment: You need to iterate through the lists within the list, instead of just the first list (which has members of type list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well your intent is not clear but it is not due to \n.

See :

```
>>> line=[['10', '13\n'], ['3', '4\n'], ['5', '3\n'], ['1', '13']]
>>> map(lambda X:([int(X[0])+1, int(X[1]) +1]),line)
[[11, 14], [4, 5], [6, 4], [2, 14]]
```

Comment: That method makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I would use a list comprehension but if you want `map`

```
map(lambda line: map(lambda s: int(s) + 1, line), lines)
```

The list comprehension would be

```
[[int(x) + 1 for x in line] for line in lines]



>>> lines=[['10', '13\n'], ['3', '4\n'], ['5', '3\n'], ['1', '13']]

>>> map(lambda line: map(lambda s: int(s) + 1, line), lines)
[[11, 14], [4, 5], [6, 4], [2, 14]]

>>> [[int(x) + 1 for x in line] for  line in lines]
[[11, 14], [4, 5], [6, 4], [2, 14]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting strings with newlines to an integer is not a problem (but `int("1a")` would be ambiguous, for example, so Python doesn't allow it).

The mapping in your code passes a sublist to the lambda function, one after another. Therefore you need to iterate over the inner lists again:

```
>>> line = [['10', '13\n'], ['3', '4\n'], ['5', '3\n'], ['1', '13']]
>>> print map(lambda sublist: map(int, sublist), line)
[[10, 13], [3, 4], [5, 3], [1, 13]]
```

For increasing by one, it would be as simple as above:

```
map(lambda sublist: map(lambda x: int(x)+1, sublist), line)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using argument unpacking.

```
pairs=[['10', '13\n'], ['3', '4\n'], ['5', '3\n'], ['1', '13']]
[[int(x) + 1, int(y) + 1] for x, y in pairs]
```

One loop, no lambda.

Comment: Thanks but a map was required.